# how to keep price of a product with custom options

Tags: custom-options, addtocart, discount, product-prices

I have products that require an 'age verification' tick before adding to basket. i have set this up as a custom option - radio button.

The price however needs to remain the same for the product, but when a customer orders more than one it discounts one of the products by 100%!

I cannot figure out how to have this verification tick on the product still but keep the price the same, regardless of how many items are ordered.

If anyone knows what i am doing wrong in the custom options please let me know.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you expand a bit, I have tried this and it works just fine.

It works OK for a single product?
You have set price for the "Tick" option to zero?
Then when you add a second product it only charges you for one?

Are you adding two of the same product so you have quantity 2 of the item?
When you say discount does it charge you and then discount afterwards?